# Show more menu items to registered members

Tags: menus

I need help with my membership site. I would like to some menu from visitors from my Main Navigation and make it visible to logged in members.

How can I achieve this, something like :

```
Home-Login-Register-Features-
```

for visitors and

```
Home-Account-downloads-Videos-Softwares-Logout-
```

for my members.

Answer (score 0):

The code for this will be:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {wp_nav_menu()} ?>
```

You can read more on menus [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and more on is_user_logged_in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)